# Mvc change action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a add patient page. When user click add patient button, I insert data to database and open treatment page. How can i do it? I tried change page in javascript but did not work:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("InsertPatient", "Addpatient")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "isim": isim, "soyisim": soyisim, "tc": tc, "cinsiyet": cinsiyet, "telefon": telefon, "telefon2": telefon2, "kangrubu": kangrubu, "dogumtrh": dogumtrh, "referans": referans, "doktor": doktor, "adres": adres }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response){
               @Layout = "~/Views/Treatment/Index.cshtml";
            }
});
```

and I tried add last row in InsertPatient function in controller:

```
RedirectToAction("Index", "Treatment");
```

Comment: When you say did not work, do you mean you never got the call on server side? You got any exception? Add any error message if you are getting it?

Comment: When I delete success property on ajax, work finely. But when Add success property did not work, did not add item to database.

Comment: Success is just your callback handler, I guess it's due to the server side code inside your function. Can you try to remove the `@Layout` line (whole) and just put `alert(response)`. See if that works

Comment: yes, as your sayed alert is works.

Comment: Your `RedirectToAction` call should work but I suspect you'd also need to supply some parameters to the `Treatment` action?

Comment: As @slugster said, I can't see any issue with your RedirectToAction call, may be Index method of your TreatmentController needs some parameter.

Comment: when I try with RedirectToAction add patient but page did not change. My all of code: https://imgur.com/a/fNB8ujz

Comment: in RedirectToAction method when click button did not get any error

Comment: I solved with: `window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Treatment")';`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a server side code inside the `onSuccess` function and expect it to work.

IF you need to redirect from JavaScript then use  `window.location = 'URL'`

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("InsertPatient", "Addpatient")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "isim": isim, "soyisim": soyisim, "tc": tc, "cinsiyet": cinsiyet, "telefon": telefon, "telefon2": telefon2, "kangrubu": kangrubu, "dogumtrh": dogumtrh, "referans": referans, "doktor": doktor, "adres": adres }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response){
               window.location = "@Url.Action("NewActionName","ControllerName")";
            }
});
```